# Sum of rows based on column value

Tags: r, plyr

I want to sum rows that have the same value in one column:

```
> df <- data.frame("1"=c("a","b","a","c","c"), "2"=c(1,5,3,6,2), "3"=c(3,3,4,5,2))
> df
  X1 X2 X3
1  a  1  3
2  b  5  3
3  a  3  4
4  c  6  5
5  c  2  2
```

For one column (X2), the data can be aggregated to get the sums of all rows that have the same X1 value:

```
> ddply(df, .(X1), summarise, X2=sum(X2))
  X1 X2
1  a  4
2  b  5
3  c  8
```

**How do I do the same for X3 and an arbitrary number of other columns except X1?**

This is the result I want:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  a  4  7
2  b  5  3
3  c  8  7
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
ddply(df, "X1", numcolwise(sum))
```

see `?numcolwise` for details and examples.

Answer (score 25):

`aggregate` can easily do this with the formula interface:

```
aggregate(. ~ X1, data=df, FUN=sum)
##   X1 X2 X3
## 1  a  4  7
## 2  b  5  3
## 3  c  8  7
```

Equivalently:

```
aggregate(cbind(X2, X3) ~ X1, data=df, FUN=sum)
```

Answer (score 6):

`aggregate` is a great function for these sorts of things:

```
aggregate(df[,-1],df["X1"],sum)

  X1 X2 X3
1  a  4  7
2  b  5  3
3  c  8  7
```

And a base R version of the `numcolwise` method from plyr:

```
aggregate(df[,sapply(df,is.numeric)],df["X1"],sum)
```

Answer (score 5):

A `data.table` solution for memory efficiency and coding elegance

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)


DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = X1]
```

`.SD` is the subset of the data.table for each group defined by the values of `X1`. There are 3 helpful vignettes associated with the `data.table` package.