# Summarizing Data across age groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, summarization

[image]I have data for customer purchases across different products , I calculated the amount_spent by multiplying Item Numbers by the respective Price

I used cut function to segregate people into  different age bins, Now how can I find the aggregate amount spent by different age groups i.e the contribution of each age group in terms of dollars spent

Please let me know if you need anymore info

I am really sorry that I can't paste the data here due to remote desktop constraints . I am actually concerned with the result I got after summarize function

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far, also dont post images of your data but `dput` it

Comment: @mtoto This data is located on a remote server , I can't copy it , allow mw to post screenshot of my code with the result

Comment: you don't need to paste your exact code. You can create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)  of what you are trying to do.

Comment: If I understood what you are trying to do is something similar to [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047742/sum-of-rows-based-on-column-value).

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
customer_transaction %>% group_by(age_gr) %>% select(amount_spent) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Though I am not sure if you want the contribution to the whole pie or just the sum in each age group.

If your data is of class `data.table` you could go with

```
customer_transaction[,sum(amount_spent),by=age_gr]
```

Comment: when I try the second method, I am getting "unused argument by  = age_gr " error , I want the sum of amount spen for each age group  exampe 25-30   3500$  ,30-40  4000 $ , ,would the output of your first and second query be same ?

Comment: Yes they would be. If you declared your data to be `data.table[customer_transaction]` then the second one should work actually.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mobile right now. I of course meant `data.table(customer_transaction)`