# How can I sum rows that with non-numeric factor in R?

Tags: r

I have data frame like this:

```
   Port   Type
1  Port1   ssh
2  Port1   ftp
3  Port2  http
4  Port1  http
5  Port2   ssh
6  Port3   ssh
7  Port3 https
8  Port4  http
9  Port2   ftp
10 Port3   ssh
11 Port3   ftp
12 Port4   ssh
```

I want to have a sum like this:

```
Port     ssh    ftp     http    https
Port1    1      1       1       0
Port2    1      1       1       0
Port3    2      1       0       1
Port4    1      0       0       1
```

I chose R because there are some other columns with numeric values, I could use R to compute mean/median/quantile quite conveniently. I searched and found this: [Sum of rows based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047742/sum-of-rows-based-on-column-value), however the code there seems to be working only on numeric element.

Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: In the 4th row, `http` should be 1 and `https` as 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `table`

```
table(df1)
#          Type
#Port    ftp http https ssh
#  Port1   1    1     0   1
#  Port2   1    1     0   1
#  Port3   1    0     1   2
#  Port4   0    1     0   1
```

---

Other option include `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, Port~Type, value.var='Type', length)
```

Comment: @LukeHuang If there are other columns, subset the columns of interest and do the `table`. i.e. `table(df1[c('Type', 'Port')])`

Comment: @LukeHuang   Just subset the columns of interest as I mentioned earlier in the comments.

Comment: Perfectly works, Thanks @akrun. Sorry for the bad description.

Comment: Hi @akrun, if number of https in all ports are 0, that is https is not in the data frame at all, but I still want to show it as all 0, what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: @LukeHuang  One option would be to convert the 'Type' column to `factor` class with all the `levels` specified  and then do the `table`. i.e. `df1$Type <- factor(df1$Type, levels=c('ftp', 'http', 'https', 'ssh'));table(df1)`  This will make sure that even if one level is absent, it will show all 0s'

Comment: great, works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the accurate answer and of course so quick response. Would you mind have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319824/generate-complicated-table-from-data-file, that question is related to this topic, I had a very ugly approach but need some expert's advices. Thanks so much.